# Cell Fracture Not Rendering

Tags: animation, modifiers

Thanks for any help!
I'm trying to learn basic cell fracture.  I animated the default cube to fall onto a slightly extruded plane and at frame 15 (when the cube hits the plane) I applied fracture with annotate (I think this used to be referred to as grease pencil).  The fracture appears to apply itself but I can't see it when I render image.  I'm still fairly new to all of this so I'm hoping I'm missing something very simple.
Thank you!

*update.  Not sure if I'm doing this update properly but I figured out that I have to delete the original plane to see the newly created "layers"(I think you call them).  Only issue I still have is that I don't want the fracture to occur until a certain frame.  I think I have to figure out some physics, like object contstraints.

I was getting very frustrated trying to figure this out and I just found this simple tutorial that went step by step.   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZG_ZMnKzVTQ